# Simple Webclient.DownloadFile not Working

Tags: c#, winforms, webclient

Just started using Windows Forms and although the documentation and info on Google seems pretty simple, I can't get my c# Windows Form app to download a file. Here's my code:

```
        string remoteUri = "http://mysite.com/file.txt";
        string fileName = @"C:\Folder";

        WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();
        myWebClient.DownloadFile(remoteUri, fileName);
```

I have confirmed that the link is active and if I type it into a browser it starts the download and that the folder exists on my computer. When I click the button that triggers this event, I get the following error:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll

Additional information: An exception occurred during a WebClient request.

What am I missing?

Comment: Well did you look at the exception? That will explain what's going on. Also, I'd suggest specifying a full *filename*, not just the *foldername*.

Comment: Also make sure that you have rights to write `C:\Folder`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WebException has an InnerException, which will say:

> Access to the path C:\Folder is denied.

Write to a file, not a folder as @JonSkeet mentioned.

Comment: Perfect that makes a lot of sense thank you both. Not I feel like an idiot for asking but how would I view that InnerException, so I can see this in the future?

Comment: @user1767270 Visual Studio will give you an exception popup with a link "View Detail". Click that.